# JS: How can I remove active class when changing row?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how I could set an active class to inactive when changing row. Eg when I first select hours 08:00 and minutes +15, they turn active, and then ever If I want to select new values on a new row,  the previous values have to turn inactive and the selected values on the new row should turn active.

```js
let datetime1 = new Date("2022-04-10 08:00:00"); // Thu Sep 16 2010 13:30:58
let datetime2 = new Date("2022-04-10 16:00:00"); // Tue Aug 18 2015 14:20:48

let open = datetime1.getHours()
let close = datetime2.getHours()
let timeDiff = close - open

let newTimeValue = new Date(open)
console.log(newTimeValue)

let timeDifference = timeDiff;
let currentTimestamp = Date.parse("2022-04-10 08:00:00");


for (let i = 0; i < timeDiff; i++) {
  let date = new Date(currentTimestamp + i * (60 * 60 * 1000) );
  let timerange = document.createElement("p");
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  let divContainer = document.createElement("div")
  let divContainerTwo = document.createElement("div")
  let spanTimeValue = document.createElement("time");
  let spanFifteen = document.createElement("time");
  let spanThirty = document.createElement("time");
  let spanFortyFive = document.createElement("time")
  
  let timeoutput = document.createTextNode(date.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeStyle: "short" }))
  let fifteen = document.createTextNode("+15");
  let thirty = document.createTextNode("+30");
  let forty = document.createTextNode("+45");
  p.setAttribute("id", "p-value");
  span.setAttribute("id","span-value");
  spanTimeValue.setAttribute("id","span-time-value");
  spanFifteen.setAttribute("id","span-fifteen");
  spanThirty.setAttribute("id","span-thirty");
  spanFortyFive.setAttribute("id","span-forty-five");
  divContainerTwo.setAttribute("id","div-container__two")
 
  spanTimeValue.className = "time_hour"
  spanFifteen.className = "time_minutes";
  spanThirty.className = "time_minutes";
  spanFortyFive.className = "time_minutes";



  document.getElementById("div-container").appendChild(spanTimeValue)
  spanTimeValue.appendChild(timeoutput)   

  document.getElementById("div-container__two").appendChild(p)
  document.getElementById("p-value").appendChild(span)
  //document.getElementById("span-value")

  spanFifteen.appendChild(fifteen)
  spanThirty.appendChild(thirty)
  spanFortyFive.appendChild(forty)


  span.appendChild(spanFifteen)
  span.appendChild(spanThirty)
  span.appendChild(spanFortyFive)
 
}

let setTime = document.querySelectorAll(".time_minutes, .time_hour"),
  previousItem = null;
  console.log(previousItem)
  setTime.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTime.forEach(btn => {
      if (btn !== previousItem) {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
        console.log(previousItem)
      }
    });
    this.classList.add('active');
    previousItem = this;
    console.log(previousItem)

  });


});
```

```css
.active {
    background:#7BB8BE;
    color: white;
  }




.box {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height:100px;
    }




#choose-time__range {
    background: #F9FCFC;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
}

#div-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#div-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


#p-value {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="choose-time__range">
        <div id="div-container"></div>
        <div id="div-container__two"></div>
      </div>



</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear, can you pls try explaining it better.

Comment: Hi Atul, I just edit my question.

Comment: Would be helpful if you clearly explained what this is supposed to do.  The code and markup don't make much sense.  If you want to select a "row" then why is each item broken up into 4 parts each with their own click handler?